# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Hybrid_Auth' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php, login

Estoy intentando crear un login en mi pagina web mediante las redes sociales pero en el momento en que intento loguearme me sale este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Hybrid_Auth' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs...

Parece como si no reconociera la clase Hybrid_Auth pero no encuentro solución...si alguien sabe a que se debe lo agradecería.

He de decir que creo tener instalado correctamente la librería HybridAuth

Este es el fichero Auth.php desde donde llamo a la clase Hybrid_Auth:

```
<?php

  class Auth
  {
    protected static $allow = ['Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Google'];

    protected static function issetRequest()
    {
      if(isset($_GET['login'])){
        if(in_array($_GET['login'], self::$allow)){
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    public static function getUserAuth()
    {
      if(self::issetRequest())
      {
        $service = $_GET['login'];

        $hybridAuth = new Hybrid_Auth(__DIR__ . '\config.php');

        $adapter = $hybridAuth->authenticate($service);

        $userProfile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

        self::storeUser($service, $userProfile);

        //redirect user
        header('Location: indexRedesSociales.php');
      }
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisando [la documentación](https://hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth/) de HybridAuth, que supongo es lo que estás usando, indica en la página principal que debes cargar la librería correspondiente.

El ejemplo en la página principal es:

```
<?php
    $config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/library/config.php';

    require_once( "library/Hybrid/Auth.php" );
 

    try{
        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );
        ...
```

Y en tu código no se ve en ninguna parte que hagas el include de la librería

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero ahora me sale otro error: **Warning: require_once(library/Hybrid/Auth.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\...** de hecho la carpeta library no la encuentro...

Comment: @Pablo Pues no la has descargado y puesto en el lugar. No es una ilbrería estándar de PHP; te corresponde incluirla

Comment: Creía tenerla instalada pues en este directorio C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth parece que esté la librería hybridauth aunque no se si realmente es lo mismo.